# ruby MySQL returns #<Mysql:0x000000016f3780> and not nil

Tags: mysql, ruby, return, null

Environment is:

```
ruby 1.9.3p392 (2013-02-22 revision 39386) [x86_64-linux]
gem: mysql (2.9.1)
```

I'm trying to extract data from MySQL in ruby. It looks like this (found at http://www.kitebird.com/articles/ruby-mysql.html)

```
def read_sql_host(hostname, mac)
hostname = "'" + "#{hostname}" + "'"
mac = "'" + "#{mac}" + "'"
res = dbh.query("SELECT macadd FROM basenode WHERE hostname = #{hostname}")

res.each do |row|
    row = row.collect { |v| v.nil? ? "nil" : v }
    return row[0]
end
dbh.close if dbh
end
```

Now - when i add:

```
puts read_sql_host("node13.abit.dk", "00-11-22-33-44-55")
```

it returns the right thing:

```
[koen@Cerberus cgi-bin]$ ruby use_sql.rb 
50:e5:49:b0:50:1a
```

But when I ask for something, that's not in the database:

```
puts read_sql_host("node66.abit.dk", "00-11-22-33-44-55")
```

It just returns something, that i have no idea, how to change?

```
[koen@Cerberus cgi-bin]$ ruby use_sql.rb 
#<Mysql:0x000000022f4818>
```

By my understanding, it should return "nil", as stated in the each-loop?

Any help would be greatly appreciated  :>

//M00kaw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You loop over the row:

```
res.each do |row|
    row = row.collect { |v| v.nil? ? "nil" : v }
    return row[0]
end
```

However when there are no rows, the `.each` will not execute and the return not reached. You will end up at the next statement:

```
dbh.close if dbh
```

which returns what `dbh.close` returns.

And just by the way: Your code looks like PHP. I would use a database abstraction layer like Sequel, which makes things easier for you. [Please take a look at the example here,](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/) this should convince you :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd highly recommend NOT using direct SQL generation, and instead use an ORM like [Sequel](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/).

ORMs abstract away the most annoying parts of talking to databases and allow you to write code that is more easily ported across DBMs.

Your use of:

```
res = dbh.query("SELECT macadd FROM basenode WHERE hostname = #{hostname}")
```

opens your code to SQL Injection attacks. Proper use of bound parameters will help mitigate that. Something like this is a good starting point:

```
res = dbh.query("SELECT macadd FROM basenode WHERE hostname = ?", hostname)
```